# Newly copied images to the localhost site on ubuntu 14.04 doesn't display, in basic img tag

Tags: php, html, image, apache, ubuntu-14.04

After I copied my old site folder to my newly installed (apache 2, ubuntu 14.04) localhost folder it works fine, but when I inserted a new img tag and copied new image to the folder, it doesn't display, but displays when I run site on hosting, I thing something wrong with folder structure or something else, please help

```
<div class="panel-body">
             <h3>Сервис и обучение</h3>

              <div class="row">
                <a href="img/turnkey/service3.jpg" data-lightbox="turnkey" data-title="Сервис и обучение" class="thumbnail col-md-3 col-md-offset-2"><img src="img/turnkey/service3.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="Сервис и обучение"></a>
                <a href="img/turnkey/service4.jpg" data-lightbox="turnkey" data-title="Сервис и обучение" class="thumbnail col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"><img src="img/turnkey/service4.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="Сервис и обучение"></a>                    
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <a href="img/turnkey/service1.jpg" data-lightbox="turnkey" data-title="Сервис и обучение" class="thumbnail col-md-3 col-md-offset-2"><img src="img/turnkey/service1.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="Сервис и обучение"></a>
                <a href="img/turnkey/service2.jpg" data-lightbox="turnkey" data-title="Сервис и обучение" class="thumbnail col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"><img src="img/turnkey/service2.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="Сервис и обучение"></a>                   
              </div>
               <a href="img/turnkey/service5.jpg" data-lightbox="turnkey" data-title="Сервис и обучение" class="thumbnail col-md-3"><img src="img/turnkey/service5.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="Сервис и обучение"></a>
            </div>
        </div><!--end of 1st panel-->
```

Comment: ok, now you see, i mean all images except lastly added the last one display normal, service5.jpg doesn't display

Comment: it would be a permissions issue

Comment: sorry for my english

Comment: how to solve that for the rest of the time, forever

Comment: I could be a caching problem of the browser as well.

Comment: Agreed, could be browser cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PERMISSIONS??**

Do a `ls` against the directory from a cli, you will see the permissions are wrong or they are owned by some other user like root and not www-data.

So try

```
cd /var/www/html/mydirectory/
ls -l
```

This will list all the files and show the owner/group and permissions. You should chown them to www-data:www-data and chmod them to so they have read access to all.

To solve this issue in the future, you need to assign a group or owner that you are editing files with.. So if sftp or something, check how to do this best with google.

**BROWSER CACHE**

If its the browser cache and other images have worked with uploading them, then it could be the cache. To test this.. simply try something like accessing the file directly in the browser with its full url. Then simply hold F5 for a few seconds or change the url to something like `http://myhostorip/mydirectory/myimage.png?nocache=1`

This can be done in the `<img src="http://myhostorip/mydirectory/myimage.png?nocache=1" />` or with a direct browser url.

Simple change the nocache parameter every time you upload, or have this generated some how.. Remove once you go live, or adjust each time a update has been done if you want to force cache reloads.